# In CakePHP, is there a way to check a find() param value (like conditions) in afterFind callback?

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.0

I'm using `find()` method in models, and a custom behavior with the `afterFind()` callback.

I would like to test my `$params` values used for the `find($type, $params)`, but in my `afterFind()` code.

Model code :

```
find('all', array('check' => 'BAR'));
```

My behavior `afterFind()` code:

```
public function afterFind(Model $Model, $results, $primary = false) {
  if ("BAR" was set ...) {
    // do something
  }
}
```

The only way I see, is to use `beforeFind()` and set a class variable to "BAR".  Check this class variable later in `afterFind()`.  But I'm worry that another `beforeFind()` occur before my `find()` and `afterFind()` will be resolved.

Any advice or solution ?

EDIT :
My question can also be read like this: can we catch, in any way, the find() $params settings in the afterFind() callback ?

Comment: would you be using this in the whole application (all models), or is this an unique case (to see if you'll be better of overwriting the find() function) ? And also, I understand what you want to do, but not why. Can't you process the params in beforeFind and do stuff there? Could you provide an example of why would you need to do something like that in afterFind depending on params passed before that can't be done in beforeFind?

Comment: For the whole app. (all models).  Want to avoid to repeat checks AFTER I get the results.  I want to do some tests, like to verify if there is at least one result (using count), ...

Comment: verifying there is at least one results is not an example of why you'd need the params in the afterFind

Comment: Something like this maybe?  `if(!empty($data[$this->alias])) { ... }`  If that's your question though, I suggest asking THAT instead of this seemingly unrelated one.

Comment: I don't understand the bigger picture of  that. What bigger problem are you trying to resolve? Checking the amount of records via php count() in afterFind() doesn't make any sense. That's something SQL is thought for and it does the job faster.

Comment: What I want to do in afterFind() is not so important I think.  The question was : can we catch, in any way, the $params settings in afterFind() callback ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I know, the only way to catch the `find()` `$params` (`$query` in behavior) in the `afterFind()` callback, is by using `beforeFind()` too.

Model:

```
$this->find('first', array('conditions' => $conditions, CHECK_AFTER_FIND => CHECK_FOO));
```

Behavior:

```
protected $_nextCheck = '';

public function beforeFind(Model $Model, $query) {
    if (array_key_exists(CHECK_AFTER_FIND, $query)) {
        $this->_nextCheck = $query[CHECK_AFTER_FIND];
    } else {
        $this->_nextCheck = '';
    }
}

public function afterFind(Model $Model, $results, $primary = false) {
    if ($this->_nextCheck == CHECK_FOO) {
        $this->checkFoo($results);
    }
}
```

I don't really like the solution, so if you know a better solution to pass the `$query` settings in `afterFind()`, let me know.